# Is it possible to execute a statement with multiple uses of "GO"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to execute a batch (as part of a larger script) on MS SQL Server and it is returning a list of errors:

`Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.`

etc

This is the batch:

```
 IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE')
 BEGIN


 DECLARE @SqlStr nvarchar(max)


 SET @SqlStr= ' 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE](
    [CONFIG_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SEARCH_BY_NAME] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [SEARCH_BY_BARCODE] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [SEARCH_BY_DOB] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_USERID] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_CHARGES] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_RESERVATIONS] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_DOB] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_STATUS] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_GENDER] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_REFS] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_LIBRARY] [nchar](1) NOT NULL, 
    [DISPLAY_EMAIL] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DISPLAY_MOBILENO] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [FOREGROUND_COLOUR] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [BACKGROUND_COLOUR] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [BUTTON_COLOR] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [BOX_COLOR] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TEXT_COLOR] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [PROFILE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CONFIG_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__SEARC__292D09F3]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [SEARCH_BY_NAME]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__SEARC__2A212E2C]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [SEARCH_BY_BARCODE]
GO                                                                                                          
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__SEARC__2B155265]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [SEARCH_BY_DOB]
GO                                                                                                          
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__2C09769E]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_USERID]
GO                                                                                                              
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__541767F8]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_CHARGES]
GO                                                                                                               
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__2CFD9AD7]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_DOB]
GO                                                                                                                
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__2DF1BF10]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_STATUS]
GO                                                                                                               
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__2EE5E349]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_GENDER]
GO                                                                                                               
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__2FDA0782]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_REFS]
GO                                                                                                               
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__30CE2BBB]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_LIBRARY]
GO                                                                                                                
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__31C24FF4]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_EMAIL]
GO                                                                                                                
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__DISPL__32B6742D]  DEFAULT (''Y'') FOR [DISPLAY_MOBILENO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__FOREG__33AA9866]  DEFAULT (''#E0F7F7'') FOR [FOREGROUND_COLOUR]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__ANS_247LI__BACKG__349EBC9F]  DEFAULT (''#00BCD4'') FOR [BACKGROUND_COLOUR]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE_BUTTON_COLOR]  DEFAULT (''#00BCD4'') FOR [BUTTON_COLOR]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE_BOX_COLOR]  DEFAULT (''#00BCD4'') FOR [BOX_COLOR]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE_TEXT_COLOR]  DEFAULT (''#FFFFFF'') FOR [TEXT_COLOR]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE_ANS_PROFILE_PROFILE_ID_fk] FOREIGN KEY([PROFILE_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ANS_PROFILE] ([PROFILE_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ANS_247LIB_CIRCDESK_CONFIG_PROFILE_ANS_PROFILE_PROFILE_ID_fk]
GO
'
 EXEC (@SqlStr)

 END
 GO
```

I know I can execute these statements one at a time, but it is preferred that this script is executed all at once, if possible.

Can you have multiple uses of "GO" in a string when using EXEC?

Comment: `GO` is an SSMS (and `sqlcmd`) keyword, not T-SQL, which acts as a batch separator. You can't use `GO` in dynamic SQL as it isn't a valid T-SQL term. If you want to execute dynamic SQL in different batches you have to make multiple calls to `sp_executesql`.

Comment: Why do you think that EXEC()ing this is any different to just running the set of queries inside the string?

Comment: `;` is a statement terminator, not a batch separator. It won't have the same effect @LittleSweetSeas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You CAN execute more than one `statement` in one `EXEC` command, but you cannot use `GO` (batch separator) within `EXEC` because it's not part of `T-SQL`:

> SQL Server provides commands that are not Transact-SQL statements, but
>   are recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server
>   Management Studio Code Editor. These commands can be used to
>   facilitate the readability and execution of batches and scripts.
>
> **GO** signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL
>   Server utilities.

[SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I had completely forgotten you can use ";" to end a statement. I replaced the GOs with a ";" and all works as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In short Go is a batch separator.

1. Batch is a group of one or multiple Transact-SQL statements sent at
   the same time from an application to SQL Server for the execution of
   the query and GO is a command which is used to tell the system that
   is the end of a batch. It is not a T-SQL statement.
2. You need to use it only when its needed. So you need to keep in mind
   that along with defining a batch using the GO command, you define
   the scope of that piece of T-SQL code.

You will have to remove instances of GO in your dynamic [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017#languageReferenceRemarksToggle)